# Exporting constants from array

Tags: javascript, export

I have a long set of exported constants in a file. Here's an excerpt:

```
...
export const COUNTER_INCREMENT_REQUESTED = 'COUNTER_INCREMENT_REQUESTED';
export const COUNTER_INCREMENT_REQUESTED_ASYNC = 'COUNTER_INCREMENT_REQUESTED_ASYNC';
export const COUNTER_DECREMENT_REQUESTED = 'COUNTER_DECREMENT_REQUESTED';
export const COUNTER_DECREMENT_REQUESTED_ASYNC = 'COUNTER_DECREMENT_REQUESTED_ASYNC';
...
```

Is there a way to create an array and loop through it, exporting each value?

```
const events = [
  ...
  'COUNTER_INCREMENT_REQUESTED',
  'COUNTER_INCREMENT_REQUESTED_ASYNC',
  'COUNTER_DECREMENT_REQUESTED',
  'COUNTER_DECREMENT_REQUESTED_ASYNC',
  ...
]

for(event of events) {
  export ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this is not possible.

One of the notable feature of ES module system is that the module structure can be statically analysed. This basically prevents programatically exporting things as you wish to do, as then it would break the static analysability.

Answer (score 1):

I did manage a variation on this by putting the constants in it's own file/module, then importing them into the module and looping over them there.

constants.js

```
export const COUNTER_INCREMENT_REQUESTED = 'COUNTER_INCREMENT_REQUESTED';
export const COUNTER_INCREMENT_REQUESTED_ASYNC = 'COUNTER_INCREMENT_REQUESTED_ASYNC';
export const COUNTER_DECREMENT_REQUESTED = 'COUNTER_DECREMENT_REQUESTED';
export const COUNTER_DECREMENT_REQUESTED_ASYNC = 'COUNTER_DECREMENT_REQUESTED_ASYNC';
```

index.js

```
import * as actions from './constants';
...
let eventEmitters = {};
for(const action in actions ) {
  ...
}
export default eventEmitters;
```